# Bound the size the of the linear combination factors for a given set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n+1$ $d$-dimensional vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1}$.

We want to write the vectors $a_{n+1}$ as a linear combination of vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, and let the $y_i \geq 0$, $i = 1,\ldots,n$ be the linear factors,

i.e. $\sum_i y_i a_i = a_{n+1}$.

Are there any paper/results on the size of $y_i$, or is it possible to formulate bounds on the size $y_i$ or on all $y$ together based on the entries of the $a$ vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n\end{bmatrix}$ be the matrix of your basis. 
With this matrix, we write $$Ay = a_{n+1}, $$ which is a simple linear equation, easily solved by the multiplication with the inverse $y=A^{-1} a_{n+1}$.

There are some results about $y$, most prominent $\|y\|_2 \leq \|A^{-1}\|_2$ , i.e. the minimal singular value of $A$. Some things follow directly from there by norm-equivalence (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Properties)).

Edit: This answer (I just realized) assumes $n=d$ which is not always true. In the case of an overdetermined system $n>d$ we can solve this system by employing the [Moore Penrose Invserse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A$ to get $y = A^+a_{n+1}$. This will basically ignore the parts of $A$ that are conditioned the worst. This gives the $y$ with minimal $\|y\|_2$. For other norms, it is not so simple.

Comment: yes but how large can this norm be?

Comment: This depends on your vectors $a_i$. If they are orthogonal and have length $1$, the answer is $1$.
If they are close to being equal (e.g. differ only in the fifth digit after the decimal) this norm can be really large. 
I just realized (see edit on main answer) that you most likely refer to an over-determined system of equations, which has other properties. I will come back to you